# Android Tablayout and statemanagement

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout, state-management

I have a tablayout setup with viewpagers that have a RecyleView adapter.
When the user clicks a list item , new activity opens. When back button is pressed the Recycleview resets to the first tab and list items.

How do i store the state of the mainactivity from where the list item was clicked?

Comment: See my code in my onBackPressed() I've made some changes, tell me ifit works or not?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry you just have to use finish() in your onBackPressed() method in the Activity. finish() method just finishes off the activity and make the user to come to the same place from where he started the transition.

Do like this and get your job done :

```
public class YuorActivity extends AppCombatActivity{
   onCreate(){
     //nothing to do here
   }

  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
       //finishes the activity and let you come to the same fragment
       super.onBackPressed();
       this.finish();      
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried that it does not work... It still resets that reclycleView and tablayout

Comment: Certain changes in my code, do like this and tell me if it works. see there is a change in my onBackPressed() method and do like this.

Answer (score 0):

I am using google sign in for this app. So when ever I return back from the intent activity the function onConnected() was called and my adapter was reset. I used some logic and stopped the execution when returned back and it works. 
Thank you for your help